# Invoke-WebRequest Not Working Inside ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to do a foreach loop to pull down a file from AWS. When I run `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $S3InstallerLoc -OutFile $S3OutFile`outside of a foreach loop on the server itself it pulls my test file down. When I stick it inside a foreach loop it does not pull down the file. When I attempt to do this from another server I am getting the following error: *Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.*

Here is the entirety of the script:

```
$Servers = "AWS-GPOTEST"
$S3InstallerLoc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test.txt"
$S3OutFile = "C:\Windows\Temp\Test.txt"

ForEach ($Server in $Servers)

{

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $S3InstallerLoc -OutFile $S3OutFile

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that you are running a version of Powershell before 6.0 and that you are running this within a WinRM session you should use the UseBasicParsing parameter.

As in:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Using:S3InstallerLoc -OutFile $Using:S3OutFile -UseBasicParsing}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

Using local variables in scripts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6#using-local-variables

Comment: Thanks, I had not tried the -UseBasicParsing. One of the reasons I got away from the Invoke-Command was I thought that wasn't needed if you're doing a foreach loop and I was running into the following error with that prior: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again." Which is confusing because I thought the argument I was passing in was valid - it's an https URL that is valid. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I have fixed the mistake in my original answer. When using variables within a scriptblock you need use $using: so the variable is passed correctly.

Comment: I've never heard of having to use $using in a scriptblock! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6#using-local-variables